# Facebook PHP SDK Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-app-requests

I am working on facebook graph API to collect all feed and videos from one group and upload in another group, all feed and photo working fine,
But when i am going to upload video and its showing error with source url.
Video uploading working with our local storage video but i want to upload from the **SOURCE URL**

Looking for solutions.

Comment: source should be a video file and not a link

Comment: **Thanks**, but is it possible to upload with source URL.?

Comment: How i upload video with source URL, is it possible or not?

Comment: That’s what the `file_url` parameter is for, I suppose.

Comment: I got the solution, Currently i am downloading the video in my local storage and then send it to the another group via facebook graph sdk